# Calculate one value based on the sum of other values within one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to solve this in R, although I know I would have done it by now in Excel, I really want to learn how to use R.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 OBJECTID CDUID SENSI_FINA FREQUENCY SUM_LENGTH

        6  5915          1        51      19178

        7  5915          2        97      21536

        8  5915          3       201      35640

        9  5915          4       551     170549

       10  5915          5       308     145126

       11  5917          1       210      28104

       12  5917          2      1897     249379
```

Now I would like to sum the `SUM_LENGTH` per `CDUID` and then calculate the percentage the `SUM_LENGTH` with `SENSI_FINAL=5` is of the summed `SUM_LENGTH` per `CDUID`

So in simple words I want to do this:

> (145123/(19178+21536+35640+170549))*100

for `CDUID =  5915` and then for the next 5917 etc..

What I did so far is I calculated the sum based on the CDUID:

```
CDlenght <- aggregate(step1$SUM_LENGTH~step1$CDUID, data=step1, sum)
```

but now I'm stuck...:-(

Comment: + 1 for example data and what you had tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `data.table` or `ddply` for this

```
library(plyr)

DT2 <- ddply(step1, .(CDUID), mutate, percent = 100* SUM_LENGTH / sum(SUM_LENGTH))

 subset(DT2, SENSI_FINA == 5)
##   OBJECTID CDUID SENSI_FINA FREQUENCY SUM_LENGTH percent
## 5       10  5915          5       308     145126 37.0192
```

I think the `data.table` syntax is more elegant, and it is more memory efficient

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(step1)

DT[,percent :=  100* SUM_LENGTH / sum(SUM_LENGTH), by = CDUID][SENSI_FINA == 5]
```

`:=` assigns by reference within `DT` (so the `percent` column will now be in `DT`

Comment: Perfect! Awesome, I have never heard of that package data.table. I will make sure that I read the description of that package, sounds like something that will be useful for my analysis.